# How to reference constants from a module in JSDoc

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, constants, jsdoc

I have the following module that exports constants:

```
/** @module my_constants */
module.exports = {
    /** @const {number} */
    STATE_FOO: 1,
    /** @const {number} */
    STATE_BAR: 2
}
```

Now I have another module where a return object can contain either one of those constants. How can I reference it?

I've tried it as follows:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Result
 * @property {string} name
 * @property {my_constants.STATE_FOO|my_constants.STATE_BAR}
 */
```

In the JSDoc output the constants are printed verbatim and not linked. Is there any way to link to the constant or to the `my_constants` module?

Answer (score 1):

One option (what i have used) is to make the typedef global:

```
/** @module my_constants */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} my_constants
 * @property {number} [STATE_FOO=1]  The foo state
 * @property {number} [STATE_BAR=2]  The bar state
 * @global
 */
module.exports = {
    STATE_FOO: 1,
    STATE_BAR: 2
}
```

then you can use it like:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Result
 * @property {string} name
 * @property {my_constants} some  Some constants
 */
```

This will make link from `some` param type to the constant type definitions when you create the jsdoc.